# Error on self.view.viewWithTag() on iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios9

I'm trying to remove a view I previously added to the view on a UIViewController. The code is working on iOS 9, but crashes on 8.3 in the simulator.

I assigned the view a tag of 100 before I added it.

For debug purposes, I checked to make sure there is a view with a tag of 100 by doing

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
    print(view.tag)
}
```

and I see an output of 100, but XCode displays

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address... )
```

on this line

```
let view = self.view.viewWithTag(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don’t use tags**. Just don’t. Apple recommend developers not to use tags anymore in this year’s [WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-231/) (14:43):

> So what I mean here is if you are using View With Tag or Set Tag UIView API and shipping code, I am going to encourage you to move away from that. .. And when you not only do not get a compiler warning, but any runtime errors you get will not say anything about your use of View With Tags.

Use **class properties** (IBOutlets) instead. This is the most common practice for today.

Comment: I'm creating the view programmatically and adding it so there is no IBOutlet

Answer (score 0):

My issue was not actually in the

```
self.view.viewWithTag
```

line. That line caused the error, but it was because I added the View to the hierarchy in the

```
viewWillLoad
```

method. That still worked fine on iOS 9.

I moved the addition of the view to the

```
viewDidLoad
```

method and it worked on both iOS8 and iOS9

Answer (score -1):

If you were using an `Nibs/XIB` the problem could be caused by your `ViewController` not being initialized correctly.

This issue is caused by the default `init()` being used by the `UIViewController`

I have also encountered this issue which was fixed by doing this code snippet

```
required init() {
    super.init(nibName: <nameOfYourNib>, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Comment: Other users might find this helpful so why downvote? @Sulthan also he never marked his answer as the correct one.